# Why: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined? React-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I need to use my state in another component, i sent it with props like that.

Okay, this is my ./HandleForm container.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";

import NotLoggedRegisterForm from "./NotLoggedRegisterForm";

export default class HandleForm extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    data: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      confirmPassword: ""
    }
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state.data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NotLoggedRegisterForm data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

this is a part of the component than receive the props.

```
const { data } = props.data;

<Input
        prefix={<Icon type="mail" style={{ color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" }} />}
        type="email"
        placeholder="Email"
        name="email"
        onChange={props.handleChange}
        value={data.email}
      />
```

And i receive that error code:

```
TypeError
Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
NotLoggedRegisterForm
/src/pages/logged/not/registerForm/NotLoggedRegisterForm.js:38:24
  35 |       placeholder="Email"
  36 |       name="email"
  37 |       onChange={props.handleChange}
> 38 |       value={data.email}
     |                  ^
  39 |     />
  40 |   )}
  41 | </FormItem>
```

Comment: there are many, many, many questions on Stack Overflow regarding your error message.  Have you searched for these questions and have you attempted to use the answers which they provide?

Comment: `const { data } = props.data;` is wrong,
Please replace to `const {data} = props`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code

`const { data } = props.data` is wrong.

Because `props` contains `data`, while `props.data` doesn't contain `data` so you may change like this.

```
const data = props.data;
// or you may use "const {data} = props;"

<Input
        prefix={<Icon type="mail" style={{ color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" }} />}
        type="email"
        placeholder="Email"
        name="email"
        onChange={props.handleChange}
        value={data.email}
      />
```

Answer (score 1):

change

`const { data } = props.data;`

into

`const { data } = props;`